# What's the relation between a class SUP and a class SUB which is defined in SUP in c++?

Tags: c++, class, iterator

I want to write a container called `my_list`:

```
template<typename T>
class my_list {
    public:
        // ...

        class iterator {
            private:
                node* it;
        }
    private:
        struct node {
            T item;
            node* next;
        }

        node* head;
        node* end;
        int count;
}
```

However, the class `iterator` can't use the the private data members in the class my_list. I looked up some c++ books, but didn't find anything about it.

Comment: Unless this is homework or for learning, prefer `std::list`.  It is already written, debugged and optimized as well as highly documented.

Answer (score 1):

Go ahead and read on the usage of friend classes in this [tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/). Iterators are quite a canonical example of proper usage of this language feature.

Is there, by the way, a reason you are not using STL data structures instead of rolling your own? See [list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/).

Comment: You just need to know the structure of the node, yet don't need to be a list's friend. In fact, iterators should be wrote so we don't need the usage of friend relationship (in most standard containers, that is possible)